# Custom object as Map key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, equals, hashcode

AS I have read that if custom objects need to be the key of map, hashcode and equals method need to override, but in my case its working without overriding it. Could someone please tell whats getting wrong ?

```
    Map<Student,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    Student s1=new Student(1,"A");
    Student s2=new Student(2,"B");
    Student s3=new Student(3,"C");

    map.put(s1,1);
    map.put(s2,2);
    map.put(s1,3);

    for(Student s:map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(map.get(s) + "->" + s.id + " " +s.name);
    }
```

Proper output:

3-> 1 A

2-> 2 B

Comment: You are reusing same object. `map.put(s1,1)` and `map.put(s1,3);` so s1.equals(s1) is always true, even without overriding `equals` method

Comment: If you want to instantiate two similar `Student` objects and have them treated as equal, then you need to override equals and hashCode.

Comment: Thanks @AntonBalaniuc

Comment: Thanks @khelwood

Answer (score 6):

It is one of the [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) of `equals` method: it is reflexive. Which means that

```
x.equals(x) == true
```

An object is always equal to itself. In this case you are relaying on default implementation of `equals` method.

```
map.put(s1,1); 
map.put(s1,3);
```

and because the default implementation is reflexive

```
s1.equals(s1) == true
```

value `1` is replaced with `3`

However result will be different if you will do something like this

```
map.put(new Student(1,"A"),3);

s1.equals(new Student(1,"A"));
```

You will need to override `hashCode` and `equals` to make it work properly.

Answer (score 4):

Built-in `hashCode()` and `equals()` works fine. They're consistent in the way required by `HashMap` (i.e.: if `hashCode()`s aren't identical, `equals()` will always return `false`). That's because every object instance will only be `equal()` to itself.

However this is often not what you want it to do. Specifically, without overriding these methods, two instances of `Student` with identical fields will not be considered equal. So this will print out three lines instead of one:

```
Map<Student,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Student s1=new Student(1,"A");
Student s2=new Student(1,"A");
Student s3=new Student(1,"A");

map.put(s1,1);
map.put(s2,2);
map.put(s3,3);

for(Student s:map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(map.get(s) + "->" + s.id + " " +s.name);
}
```

(Note: technically this is all perfectly correct, but is not necessarily what most people reading your code would expect to happen.)

Answer (score 3):

If there is no overriding hashCode nor equals method, Java compares object references. Thus, `s1` reference is the same as `s1` reference, so you can replace `s1` associated value with another.

If you create a new `Student` object with the same attributes values than `s1`, and try to insert it into your map, you'll have two different pairs.